# How do I request core maintainers attention in drupal.org issue queues?

Tags: community-official-site

A white ago I have discovered a bug in Drupal. However, in my attempt of fixing it, I ran into a few walls. The main reason probably being that I miss history (e.g. why several decisions have been made).

It there a tag, status, or anything else to signal the core maintainers that I am stuck in resolving the issue?

Comment: Thanks for the down vote... If there is something obvious I have missed, could you please share it with me. I'd say that it is pretty common that people get stuck resolving issues, so there should be some system to indicate to maintainers that you need a little push in the right direction right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a list of usable tags here : https://www.drupal.org/issue-tags
Browse this and the following pages to get an understanding of using tags in the issue queue.
You could also mention the bug in irc on freenode #drupal-contribute.
You can tweet about it. Or you could post a link to the issue here!?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Lars, but I do not think this is the place for people to start posting issues for which they need maintainer info (it is not really an answerable question). irc might work, but I have never touched that yet. I was hoping for a way to do it in the Drupal.org issue queue.

Comment: I want ahead with the `Needs committer feedback` tag for now. Thanks for the list.